# How to get context from onStartCommand

Tags: android

I have a service and I need to get access to context from the service onStartCommand.

How could I do that. I'm new to Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ServiceName.this` to get `Context`, `Service` extends `Context`

Answer (score 1):

[Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a Context. You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.`. [Service extends a Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).